# How to properly bind current object context in ES6 using babelify

Tags: babeljs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to bind current instance to the class method, please note ES6 syntax.

```
class SomeClass {

  search() => { ... }

}
```

Which is 100% legit code, however, babelify doesn't want to compile it

```
SyntaxError: /Users/vladmiller/Projects/test/test/client/test/app/pages/Search.react.js: Unexpected token (50:26) while parsing file: /Users/vladmiller/Projects/test/test/client/test/app/pages/Search.react.js\
```

Instead, now I have to bind context in class constructor

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.search = this.search.bind(this)
  }
  search() { ... }
}
```

Which is quite annoying and boring.

**UPD:** It turns out that this is invalid ES6 syntax; therefore the question is follows. What is the best way to bind instance context to a class method?

**UPD2:** By default context should be attached, however, the issue with React http://jsbin.com/citafaradu/2/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Why do you think this was 100% legit code? It's coffeescript syntax, not ES6.

Comment: I assumed that if ES6 support arrows this should actually work on class level as well https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#arrows

Comment: And WebStorm didn't give me any warning on this syntax

Comment: Is there any better way to bind instance to class method?

Comment: *Instead now I have to bind context in class constructor*. No you don't, it's already bound. `search() { console.log(this) // logs SomeClass }` - assuming of course that the context of this hasn't been changed by the caller. [Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20SomeClass%20%7B%0A%20%20search()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Avar%20c%20%3D%20new%20SomeClass()%3B%0Ac.search()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Correct%20context%2C%20as%20it%20should%20be%20called%0Ac.search.call(window)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Modified%20context)

Comment: @RGraham Here is a quick example, looks like with React context is not bind http://jsbin.com/citafaradu/2/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @VladMiller: Those babel docs don't use an arrow as part of a class body anywhere either?

Comment: Well, no. It's just was confusing because in React docs it is stated that you can use arrow to bind the context. I think this question is closed now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is not valid ES2015. Prototype methods are defined like this:

```
class SomeClass {

  search() { /* ... */ }

}
```