# Simplified way to bind methods to constructor?

Tags: javascript

Given the class below as an example:

```
class BestClassEver {
    constructor() {
        let self = this;
        self.doSomethingOne = self.doSomethingOne.bind(self);
        self.doSomethingTwo = self.doSomethingTwo.bind(self);
        self.doSomethingThree = self.doSomethingThree.bind(self);
        self.doSomethingFour = self.doSomethingFour.bind(self);
        self.doSomethingFive = self.doSomethingFive.bind(self);
    }

    doSomethingOne(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this? If I had 20 methods it could get lengthy. Unless there is a way to automatically bind methods to `this` like an arrow function would. I've tried to use arrow functions but my compiler throws errors.

Comment: Why do you need to bind in the first place? If you defined the method as part of the class it automatically has access to `this`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314924/do-es2015-classes-not-autobind

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties.html to the rescue

Comment: @UnholySheep When you export that class, you dont have access to any methods inside of it, unless you bind them to the constructor.

Comment: Starting to seem like an X/Y problem. Instead of asking about your solution to the problem, can you update the question to describe the actual problem in more detail?

Comment: please add a problem to the pattern.

Comment: Use arrow functions instead of function declarations. They are by default bonded to their class.